# Javascript InnerHTML Output Wrong

Tags: javascript, html, string, tags, innerhtml

```
function test()
{
var formHTML ="";
var frmid ="test123";

var options = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"]
formHTML += "<select id='" + frmid + ">";

console.log(options);

for ( i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    var temp = options[i];
    var temp2 = "<option value='" + temp + "'>" + temp + "</option>";
    console.log(temp2);
    formHTML += temp2;
}
formHTML += "</select>";
console.log(formHTML); 
document.getElementById("injected").innerHTML+=formHTML;
```

}

Above is my function to make a select element in my page, when i call this function there is a very strange issue, it only dispalys options test2,test3,test4,test5 and not one...

When i print out formHTML using console.log it shows..

```
<select id='test123><option value='Test1'>Test1</option>
<option value='Test2'>Test2</option>
<option value='Test3'>Test3</option>
<option value='Test4'>Test4</option>
<option value='Test5'>Test5</option>
</select>
```

But if you run the code and look at the source code the HTML element is not correct the first element looks like

```
 <option value='test1'> Test1
```

Missing the close option tag,

I have tried debugging and changing code around but this issue has left me confused.

Is there something missing is there better way of going about this? I am trying to store it all in one string before manipulating the DOM for speed reasons.
All help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: FWIW, with Pure-JS DOM manipulation like this I (rightly or wrongly) prefer to use `document.createElement()` and friends to avoid potential errors and ambiguities that come with string manipulation of variables. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/2GNPB/)

Comment: Apart from preferring it, what is the advantages of doing it this way? Are you able to see me away to dynamicly inject a script? Like we are doing witht the select?

Comment: When you say `dynamicly inject a script` do you mean `dynamically add another <script> tag to the document`?

Comment: Yes thats correct, i have my name javasscript file general.js and from that file i want to be able to add javascript tag to the document...

Comment: Well it's basically just a case of `var newScript = document.createElement('script'); newScript.type = 'text/javascript'; newScript.src = 'http://wherever.com/whatever.js'; document.body.appendChild(newScript);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

YOu have an error in this line

```
formHTML += "<select id='" + frmid + ">";
```

Change that to

```
formHTML += "<select id='" + frmid + "'>";
```

Comment: Thanks, Such small issue bit majorly annoying, cant belive i missed that out ! Is there anything im doing thats considered back practice or a better way to do it? Thanks

Comment: Your code is fine ! Although pure javascript is good, i suggest you to use jquery that makes it much easier to do these kind of jobs